# Creating video from Processing program

Tags: video, processing

I am working with the Processing package for creating visualizations. What I see in the end is an Animated Video which plots the large amount of Mobile Transaction data that I have. I know that I can export the application as JavaScript, but I can more interested in creating the video because I want to set to a particular frame rate.

Does anyone know of a package or some way to create the video using Processing such that I can manipulate the framerate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a video core library built in Processing. Until 1.5.1, there were a MovieMaker class with an addFrame() method to be called in the end of draw. This have been removed in 2.0x. You can yet use 1.5.1 to this. Alternatively you can just [save](http://processing.org/reference/saveFrame_.html) frames each draw() loop and then assemble them as a movie using Quicktime 7 or some other tools. Works like a charm.

```
void draw(){
//do draw

saveFrame("name-####.tif");// use .tga or .jpg or .png 
 }
```